# R - concatenate rows from single column on groups - optimization

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to concatenate all rows from a single column into single row and apply it on groups.
I've figured out a solution using dplyr::do and dplyr::summarize and it works good on small datasets, however it is EXTREMELY slow on larger data sets.

Maybe someone has an idea how to optimize this?
Already checked: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990164/r-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-one-beside-each-other)

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A",3), rep("B", 3)),
                 value = c(rep("C",3), rep("D",3)))
```

```
joined_vec <- df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
    dplyr::do(
      dplyr::summarize(.,
                       value_joined = dplyr::pull(., value) %>% paste(collapse = " ")
      )
    ) %>% dplyr::pull(value_joined)
```

Output:

```
> joined_vec
[1] "C C C" "D D D"
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Instead of `tostring` in the link, use your `paste(collapse = " ")`. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do without the `do` and `pull` part because you are just operating on the column:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
summarize(value_joined=paste(value,collapse=" ")) %>% 
pull(value_joined)

[1] "C C C" "D D D"
```

You can also do this in base R:

```
tapply(df$value,df$group,paste,collapse=" ")
      A       B 
"C C C" "D D D"
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, first is ~6x faster, but using tapply it's ~50x :)